# Members - Can a member turn off email notifications for messages?

Tags: members, email, notification, messages

Can a member turn off email notifications for messages?

If so, is there a way to save this setting for each member in a Safecracker form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are using Safecracker Registration for the member registration process. For turning off the email notification for messages the member's `notify_of_pm` need to be set as 'n'. Can you just try by having an input field within form tag:

```
<input type="text" name="notify_of_pm" value="n" />
```

and then check within exp_members for `notify_of_pm` column value for that member if set as 'n'.

If it didn't work, you will need to create an extension for it which will update it.

Comment: Yep, that is the field name alright. I have to use an extension hook, however.